# Persistent FID in Geoserver WFS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs

My organisation uses a SAAS and part of that service publishes data via a WFS using Geoserver 2.7.0. I have sent a GetFeature request via a browser (IE11) and it returns the GML however, if I refresh the link the FID changes:

:wfs_BBQ gml:id="wfs_BBQ.fid-74424e53_159f7837ba8_350">

:wfs_BBQ gml:id="wfs_BBQ.fid-74424e53_159f7837ba8_ec3">

I am using QGIS 2.18.3 (running on Win 10) and I'm told QGIS needs persistent FIDs (see: [Duplicate WFS Featues in QGIS 2.18.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225608/duplicate-wfs-featues-in-qgis-2-18-3)) and that Geoserver should create a persistent FID if the WFS has a Primary Key. The data does have a Unique ID (integer) so I'm hoping this meets the requirement.

How do I ensure the FIDs are persistent?

Comment: See also [A GeoServer layer is based on PostGis view, but featureID is random (PK is ignored)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64008/a-geoserver-layer-is-based-on-postgis-view-but-featureid-is-random-pk-is-ignor), and my answer there about creating a GeoServer view that is just a `select * from my_view` to get stable ids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To generate a permanent FID [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) (which underlies [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org)) uses whatever the underlying datastore provides. So if you are querying a database should be the primary key. So if your FIDs change the problem is likely that you haven't set a primary key up for your table, or GeoTools can't work out what it is. This may occur if you are using a view, to fix this you can [create a metadata table](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/primarykey.html) to help out.

You would also see this effect if you were foolish enough to try to run a WFS on top of a Shapefile, here the solution is not to do that.

Comment: It took a while to get this change implemented but now that I have static FIDs I get the correct number of records. BTW If anyone else has this issue then using a distinct query as a work-around seemed to work while waiting for the fix to be implemented.